# CVXPY 's constrains doesn't work

Tags: portfolio-optimization, mean-variance, black-litterman

I am trying to implement a max return optimization with a large number of assets. I am not sure why this problem won't work.

```
w = cvxpy.Variable(num_asset) #30 assets
constraints = []
constraints.append(cvxpy.abs(w) <= 1)
constraints.append(cvxpy.sum_entries(w) == 1)
objective = cvxpy.Maximize(combined_return.T * w - 0.5 * alpha * cvxpy.quad_form(w, combined_covariance))
problem = cvxpy.Problem(objective)
problem.solve(solver='CVXOPT', verbose=True)
```

The result have 3 of the weights way greater than 1.

```
          Holding
PCLN     0.024891
MHK      0.005428
**AZO    -14.429484**
SJM      0.006767
COST     0.027336
CLX      0.006752
TSO      0.003282
VLO      0.008457
PSX      0.014839
BLK      0.021508
ICE      0.011146
EQR      0.009720
ISRG     0.009747
BIIB     0.020765
GILD     0.043480
UAL      0.005269
GWW      0.005330
LMT      0.028927
**GOOGL   14.624353**
GOOG     0.182734
**IBM    121.617234**
SHW      0.010577
LYB      0.012353
EMN      0.003821
LVLT     0.007118
VZ       0.085949
T        0.098943
NEE      0.022617
SRE      0.010750
AEP      0.013104
```

Could someone help me understand why that constraint cvxpy.abs(w)<=1 doesn't do the job? Many thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you include `constraints` as a parameter to the call to `Problem`?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include `constraints` as a parameter to the call to `Problem`.